# Laravel module autoload policy confusion

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

When executing

```
   php artisan workbench user/asset
```

additional dependency(module) placed to

```
   workbench/user/asset/vendor/illuminate/support.
```

Then framework autoload this module(**illuminate/support**) from **workbench/user/asset/vendor/***, but i think it must load it from **/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/**

So we have confusion here - some classes are loaded from framework(**vendor/laravel/***) and some classes are loaded from **workbench/[vendor]/[module]**. Is that supposed to work that way? Or is it a bug?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Workbenches are supposed to help you develop packages, they have their own `vendor` folder, which stores their and noone else's dependencies. Once your workbench package is complete, publish it (or keep it private) and install it using Composer. After all of this, dependencies in `root/vendor` are loaded instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and No.

During development of your package it will work that way, because the whole structure is inside `/workbench`. It also helps you working in different versions of packages, develop using Laravel 4.1 while your app is still on 4.0.

After you finish working on your package, it's better to create a real Composer package. You can create a private one and then, yeah, once you install it via Composer it will be placed in `/vendor`.